# How to create a side-by-side bar chart with SE bars in R

Tags: r, graph

I am creating a side-by-side bar chart with Standard Error bars from a Two-way ANOVA table in R studio. The complete version of bar chart should look like this:

[image: example bar chart]

The data we are working with is in Excel:

[Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3vnG.png)

and simply in text form:

Currently I have created a table in R studio, but I don't know what to do next and how to calculate the mean, standard errors etc. A part of the table I've created is in this link: [two-way ANOVA  table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7Xe4.png)

Here is my table in R studio:

```
dput(tidyadhd)

structure(list(voltage = c(9.5, 10, 9.2, 6, 9, 11, 9, 9.2, 8, 
9, 11, 9, 8.2, 8, 9, 9, 6, NA, 9.5, 9, 7.1, 9.3, 9, 9.5, 9, 9.2, 
9.3, 9, 8.5, 9, 9.2, 9.3, 8.2, 9, 9.3, NA, 9.5, 9, 9.2, 9.3,    
9, 9.5, 9, 9.2, 9.3, 9, 9.5, 9, 9, 9, 9.3, 8, 7, 8, 5.1, 4.3, 
4.5, 5.3, 4.5, 5.1, 4.3, 4.5, 5.3, 4.5, 5.1, 4.3, 4.3, 4.3, 5.3, 
6.4, 5, 8), state = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("Rest", "Cue"), class = "factor"), treatment = 
c("placebo", 
"placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", 
"placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", 
"placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", 
"placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", 
"placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", 
"placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "ritalin", 
"ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", 
"ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", 
"ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", 
"ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", 
"ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", 
"ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin"), patient = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L)), .Names = c("voltage", "state", "treatment", "patient"
), row.names = c(NA, -72L), class = "data.frame")
```

Can someone help me to create a bar chart from the table above please? Because I've tried to do this myself for over 24 hours and it just keeps telling me errors. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please post data as raw text (using _e.g._ `dput`), not images, so other users can copy/paste it.

Comment: I've used 'dput' function in R and I have copied and pasted the output came up in R. Can you help me please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of ideas using `ggplot2`. I recommend spending some time learning how to use this package - [start here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/).

The first step is deciding how to group the variables in your data. I'm assuming that `voltage` is the dependent variable and you're interested in the effect of `treatment` for each of the two `state`. So you want to plot voltage versus state, and `facet` by treatment.

You can either preprocess the data to calculate means and standard errors, or use `stat_summary` to do it for you. You could colour the bars by state but I don't think that's necessary here as the axis labels are clear.

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())

ggplot(tidyadhd, aes(state, voltage)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "bar", fill = "grey70") + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.4) +
  facet_wrap(~treatment)
```

[image]

These so-called "dynamite plots" are often criticised ([example](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/StripchartOverlaidWithBoxplot)) and boxplots are suggested as a better alternative:

```
ggplot(tidyadhd, aes(state, voltage)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~treatment)
```

[image]

One more alternative is to show the individual data points using `geom_jitter`. This works here as we don't have too many observations; in this case it probably does help to colour the points by `state`. If you don't need the colours in a legend, use `guides()` as shown.

You could add `stat_summary` to this plot too, to show means with error bars.

```
ggplot(tidyadhd, aes(state, voltage)) + 
  geom_jitter(width = 0.2, size = 2, aes(color = state)) +
  facet_wrap(~treatment) + 
  guides(color = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!! You have saved me from a disaster!! This is a part of my assessment project and I've completed everything except this graph and this project is due in today... I'll give it a try now and fortunately I will be able to hand it in on time. Thanks again.

Comment: Just for interest, I have a question about changing the axis label. How do I change the y-axis label from "Voltage" into "Voltage(μV)"?